# Accidently deleted every file in Vs Code while trying to push to git, any way to recover them?

Tags: visual-studio-code, recover

I am a complete noob so while trying to deploy one of my programs to heroku, I needed to push it to github, in Vscode while trying to do that, I got a whole bunch of files that I didn't want to upload on github, so I hit remove all from this screen

[image]

I now realize that I deleted everything and I don't know what I can do, I tried going into my drive and hitting properties to try and restore but looks like I hadn't turned that feature on. Is there anyway I can recover my files? I am on windows

Comment: There are so many things that could be happening, since youre new to this all and the screenshot isnt really saying anything.

You probably didnt delete anything but just dont track it anymore so its not showed in the git tab. Are the project files still in the project directory?

Comment: on vscode I still see my original .py files under open editor section, but under data where it was previously, its blank and when I try and click on those .py files I get an error file cannot be opened because its not found

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to your terminal and navigate to the folder you are pushing to git. You can run these commands:

`git log --pretty=oneline` (Shows all previous commits)

`git checkout .` (This resets everything to the previous commit)

Once you have reset your project to the previous commit, try again and delete the files you wanted to remove. Then perform the `git commit -am "text here"` and `git push heroku master` commands.

EDIT: This only works if you have already made git commits. If you have deleted everything and `git log --pretty=oneline` does not show any commits, then there is no way to recover the deleted files.

You can also check the recycle bin of your computer to see if the deleted files are there.

Comment: when I try to do git log --pretty=oneline I get error saying your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet

Comment: If you don't have any commits, then you can't reset your project.

Comment: is there a function like time machine on mac that I can try on windows? It was about 2 weeks of stuff so I am desperate

Comment: 2 weeks without any backup is trying your luck on trusting hardware and making mistakes, let this be a lesson that (daily) backups are very handy

Comment: @NunMatters Go to the Recycle Bin on your desktop and see if the files are there

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to VScode Timeline feature I could restore the file. Timeline tab has files local history